# How does having 2 recursive statements within the same conditional work?

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to understand how this recursive code works, and I haven't found anything similar to it on the internet.

```java
public void doSomething(int n)
{
    if (n > 0)
    {
        doSomething(n-1);
        System.out.println(n);
        doSomething(n-1);
    }
}

Why is the output 1213121?
```

Comment: *"Why is the output ...?"* - set a breakpoint and step through the code line by line.

Comment: if you didn't find anything on the internet u haven't tried enough. this is a common practice. Have a look at how tree traversal works.

Comment: It works by calling the method, then printing something ***after*** the method call has completed, then calling the method again.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple.

You call `doSomething(3)` -> `doSomething(2)` -> `doSomething(1)` -> `doSomething(0)` -> condition is not met so you `return` -> `println(1)` -> `doSomething(0)` -> condition is not met so you `return`.

Now you are at the end of the function `doSomething(1)`. `println(2)` is called.
And you call `doSomething(1)` same as before.

When you return from `doSomething(2)`, `println(3)` is called...